# simple rendering angularjs scope data in the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

inside angularjs controller I have some dummy data

```
$scope.someData = {
        "A": "AAAA",
        "B": "BBBB",
        "C": "CCCC"
};
```

from my view (which is bounded to the route which calls above controller)

```
<li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="data in someData">
    {{data.A}} | {{data.B}} | {{data.C}}    
</li>
```

I'm getting rendered view

| | |

| | |

| | |

but when I look with batarang chrome extension I am able to see this scope data trough this plugin

```
Models for (4)
 { 
    data: AAAA
 } 
Models for (5)
 { 
    data: BBBB
 } 
Models for (6)
 { 
    data: CCCC
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iterate over an object, not an array. So inside the ng-repeat scope you have "data" which then holds the value of each iteration (AAAA, BBBB, CCCC). You should probably change the dummy data to be an array with one object.

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.someData = [{
        "A": "AAAA",
        "B": "BBBB",
        "C": "CCCC"
    }];
}

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="data in someData">
    {{data.A}} | {{data.B}} | {{data.C}}    
  </li>
</div>
```

Output:

```
AAAA | BBBB | CCCC
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably this will lead to the desired solution:

```
<li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="(key,value) in someData" >
{{key}} | {{value}}   
</li>
```